# Client = discord.client() TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, discord.py

Why I am I getting `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable` with my code?

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import time
Client = discord.Client() 
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "?") 
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is online and connected to Discord")
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
 if message.content == "cookie":
 await client.send_message(message.channel, ":cookie:")
client.run("...")
```

Full error:

> Error: Client = discord.client() TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: Your tittle looks like it would throw the error, but your example looks fixed. https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/async/discord/__init__.py#L20 Whats the new issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Client = discord.Client()
```

Remove this line entirely.  You aren't using `Client` anywhere, and `discord.ext.commands.Bot` is a subclass of `discord.Client`, so you can access all of the `Client` attributes through `Bot`.