# Why does discord.py-rewrite bot.loop.create_task(my_background_task()) execute once but does not repeat

Tags: discord.py

Using Discord.py-rewrite, *How can we diagnose `my_background_task` to find the reason why its print statement is not printing every 3 seconds?*

**Details:**
The problem that I am observing is that "`print('inside loop')`" is printed *once* in my logs, but not the expected 'every three seconds'. Could there be an exception somewhere that I am not catching?

Note: I *do* see `print(f'Logged in as {bot.user.name} - {bot.user.id}')` in the logs so `on_ready` seems to work, so that method cannot be to blame.

I tried following this example: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/async/examples/background_task.py
however I did not use its `client = discord.Client()` statement because I think I can achieve the same using "bot" similar to as explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/53136140/6200445

```
import asyncio
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

token = open("token.txt", "r").read()


def get_prefix(client, message):

    prefixes = ['=', '==']    

    if not message.guild:
        prefixes = ['==']   # Only allow '==' as a prefix when in DMs, this is optional

    # Allow users to @mention the bot instead of using a prefix when using a command. Also optional
    # Do `return prefixes` if u don't want to allow mentions instead of prefix.
    return commands.when_mentioned_or(*prefixes)(client, message)


bot = commands.Bot(                         # Create a new bot
    command_prefix=get_prefix,              # Set the prefix
    description='A bot for doing cool things. Commands list:',  # description for the bot
    case_insensitive=True                   # Make the commands case insensitive
)

# case_insensitive=True is used as the commands are case sensitive by default

cogs = ['cogs.basic','cogs.embed']


@bot.event
async def on_ready():                                       # Do this when the bot is logged in
    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user.name} - {bot.user.id}')  # Print the name and ID of the bot logged in.
    for cog in cogs:
        bot.load_extension(cog)
    return


async def my_background_task():
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    print('inside loop') # This prints one time. How to make it print every 3 seconds?
    counter = 0
    while not bot.is_closed:
        counter += 1
        await bot.send_message(channel, counter)
        await channel.send(counter)
        await asyncio.sleep(3) # task runs every 3 seconds

bot.loop.create_task(my_background_task())
bot.run(token)
[]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a cursory inspection, it would seem your problem is that you *are* only calling it once. Your *method* `my_background_task` is not called once every three seconds. It is instead your `send_message` method that is called once every three seconds. For intended behavior, place the print statement inside your while loop.

Answer (score 1):

Although I am using rewrite, I found both of these resources helpful.
https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/async/examples/background_task.py
https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/rewrite/examples/background_task.py

Comment: The second link is outdated.