# TypeError when trying to declare a bot prefix

Tags: python, discord

having problems with this piece of code here. i was following a tutorial and basically copied word for word. the error im getting is `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable` on line 6.

here is my code

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

token = '(my token here)'

client = commands.bot(command_prefix = '.')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print ('ready')
    client.run(token)
```

sorry this is so poorly described, im fairly new to python and the discord API

Comment: Please include the full traceback, and a link to the actual tutorial. Clearly `commands.bot` ends up being something else than the tutorial's author expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try importing this:

```
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
```

and change the client to this:

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ".")
```

based on the code snippet in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53135800/client-discord-client-typeerror-module-object-is-not-callable) question

Answer (score 0):

This error statement `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable` is raised as you are confusing about the Class name and Module name. You are importing a module, not a class. This happens because the module name and class name have the same name .
Try

```
from discord import discord
```

Comment: i get the error ImportError: cannot import name 'discord' from 'discord'

Answer (score 0):

the error was happening because im dumb and didnt capitalise the `.Bot` in `commands.bot`